# How to use conditional if/else for multiple dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I've been been trying the lat and long of dataframe using geocoder.

I managed to get the lat/long of distict city and save it into a file. However, I got an error when try to map the data to other data of city as Im not sure how to do so.

My code:

```
def func(a):
    if a in data2['CITY']:
        return data2['LATITUDE']
    else:
        return "0"

data["LATITUDE"] = data["CITY"].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Comment: "I got an error" - what's the error?

Comment: Sidenote: `lambda x: func(x)` is redundant. Just use `func`. This is called eta-reduction btw.

Comment: With `data2 = pd.to_excel(r'/')`, I get `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_excel'`. Maybe you meant `pd.read_excel()`? But then you'd get `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'`. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: yes correct. edited with sample dataset

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(deduplokasi.head().to_dict()` and `print(data2.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: Updated question post as suggested in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can generate `data['LATITUDE']` by reindexing.

Set `data2`'s index to `CITY` and [**`reindex()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) against `data`'s `CITY`:

```
data['LATITUDE'] = data2.set_index('CITY').reindex(data['CITY'])['LATITUDE'].values
```

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas`, if you check if a certain element is in a `pd.Series`, you need to first get it to an array form:

```
'SCOTLAND' in data2['CITY'] -> False
'SCOTLAND' in data2['CITY'].values -> True
```

After making this fix, you need to make it so that it returns a single element, not a vector. So, finally:

```
def func(a):
    if a in data2['CITY'].values:
        return data2.loc[data2['CITY'] == a, 'LATITUDE'].item()
    else:
        return "0"
```